# Why is NeoVim throwing so many errors with C++?

Tags: c++, neovim

I am just getting started in C++ using NeoVim and there are tons of errors being thrown on very basic lines of code. I believe I have everything formatted properly as far as plugins and servers go. I have LLVM, clang, swig, and G++ installed. I will attach [my "Hello World" code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ3hc.png). It compiles just fine but I want to get rid of all the errors on the side! Thank you in advance!

Comment: NeoVim is just an editor and does not show any errors by default. Why you're seeing those errors depends on the plugins you have setup, but it looks your LSP setup is unable to fund standard headers.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback! I think you are definitely right, it could have to do with LSP, but as I am a beginner I am looking for specific steps to take to configure it correctly! Google has not been very useful on this front.

Comment: There are actually multiple LSP clients available for neovim including the built-in LSP in neovim 0.5. I'm not sure which one you use, but whichever one you use, it's documentation page probably has instructions on how to set it up for cpp. For example, I use https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim and the coc-clangd for cpp, and the coc-clangd github page (https://github.com/clangd/coc-clangd) along with coc.nvim page gives you all the setup instructions

Comment: Cool, I am using both of those and yet still getting the errors, even enabled the :CocConfig to allow for C++ support... Appreciate the response but still have more configuring to do I guess!

Comment: The only 2 things I do to setup coc-clangd for cpp is to have the clangd server somewhere in my `PATH` and install coc-clangd in coc.nvim. I didn't have to do any changes to my coc-settings. If you prefer to take a look at my config, it's all available in github here, https://github.com/anirudhsundar/dotfiles, although this is a personal use repo and probably not well documented.

Comment: Very cool! Thank you for your input! I finally solved this by creating a .ccls file and adding some specific code to the file, I documented my journey here- https://medium.com/geekculture/configuring-neovim-for-c-development-in-2021-33f86296a8b3

Comment: Ah okay, you're using ccls insead of clangd. I don't know about ccls, but it looks like a nice post. Might be quite useful to new comers, thanks.